# How the Spring boot works with DispatcherServlet to call the correct mapped api with jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot with jersey. Here, I extend SpringBootServletInitializer with my Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.pqr.configuration", "com.pqr.other"})
class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication .class);
    }
}
/*jersey config class*/
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
class JerseyConfig extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig{

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.pqr.service");
    }
}
```

I want to understand how the controller communicates with DispatcherServlet here and url are handled? If there is another flow, please mention. There are many concepts involved like Restcontrollers, InternalViewResolver, UrlHandler etc. I need to know what exactly happens in background?

Comment: I saw one relevant high level answer but I need to know in depth.  Component Scan searches for the beans with @Configuration and instantiates them in IOC container. The dispatcher servlet with the help of RestController does the handler mappings. But where does jersey play its role? How do these mappings work? There should be some init, pre-init behaviour. Please reply.

Comment: I referred http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/restful.html#33 link.